# Grouping Values With C# And LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ question.  Let's say I have a database with the following values:

```
===================
Date,product,orders
-------------------
1/2/2003,apple,3
1/2/2003,orange,5
1/3/2003,orange,6
1/4/2003,grape,2
===================
```

How can I use LINQ to get a result that groups the items by date and puts them into a variable that looks like this:

```
==========================
Date, Apple, Orange, Grape
--------------------------
1/2/2003,3,5,0
1/3/2003,0,6,0
1/3/2003,0 0,2
==========================
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Please reformat with the code style to make it more readable. Try to rephrase the question so it becomes more clear. Also show the table structure and the desired structure.

Comment: Seems like a Pivot is what is being asked for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here the test I done:

```
var data = new []{
    new { Date = new DateTime(2003, 1, 2), Product = "apple", Orders = (int?) 3 },
    new { Date = new DateTime(2003, 1, 3),Product =  "orange", Orders = (int?) 5 },
    new { Date = new DateTime(2003, 1, 4), Product = "grape", Orders = (int?) 2 },
    new { Date = new DateTime(2003, 1, 4), Product = "grape", Orders = (int?) null }
};

var result = data.GroupBy(x => x.Date)
                 .Select(g => new {
                   Date = g.Key,
                   Apples = g.Where(x => x.Product == "apple").Sum(x => x.Orders),
                   Oranges = g.Where(x => x.Product == "orange").Sum(x => x.Orders),
                   Grapes = g.Where(x => x.Product == "grape").Sum(x => x.Orders)
                 });
```

The result for the test data does not contain nulls, but 0 for Apples, Oranges, and Grapes.

Comment: How can I handle a situation where 

Apples = g.Where(x => x.Product == "apple").Sum(x => x.Orders),

returns a null value?  can I have it return a 0 instead of a null in this case?

Comment: See modified solution. I have not tested it but AFAIK it should work when x.Orders returns null.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: 

Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'int'

Thanks for the help so far

Comment: Figured it out.  It needs to follow this form:
Apples = (int?)g.Where(x => x.Product == "apple").Sum(x => x.Orders),

But your suggestion of using the coalescing operator lead me on the right track.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Acceptance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq to SQL, you could do something like;

var query = from p in products orderby p.Date select p;

I'm not sure what you mean by "puts them into a variable".

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var x = from tb in mytable
        group date by tb.date;
```